# Can I store numeric constants in the values folder?

Tags: android

For string constants the *values* folder can already be used to store global values.
Can the same thing be done for numeric values?
Or am I obliged to declare all the constants in a singleton (or `Application` implementation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to store integer values you can still use [Integer Resource Style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer). Unfortunately float values are not supported as resource types. Take a look at [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) for further informations.
Eventually you can always use a simple class full of static fields if that fits your needs.

Comment: You can store floats as string in the resources, and read them with `Float.parseFloat()`.